# Native IPv6 router on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, ipv6

I need your help to configure native IPv6 router on FreeBSD.

1. Interfaces configured well, on both I can see two addresses (real and link local).
2. I can `ping ipv6.google.com` and when do `lynx www.kame.net`, I can see phrase: dancing kame.
3. I installed `radvd` and get IPv6 address from server.
4. I'm using SSH connecting from my local computer to server using IPv6 address.
5. I can ping from local net both my router interfaces.
6. Using `tcpdump` on both interfaces, I can see that echo requests from my local computer are going to `ipv6.google.com`, but without response.

So, I think that my server doesn't work as router. As prove of my words, when I do ping on my external interface:

```
 ping6 -I em0 FF02::2
```

(Pinging link local addresses of neighbor routers.) I can't see my router link local address in this list. So, my router doesn't advertise herself as router and nobody know about my subnet.

Here is `rc.conf` cut:

```
ipv6_activate_all_interfaces="YES"
ip6addrctl_enable="YES"
ip6addrctl_policy="ipv6_prefer"
ifconfig_em0_ipv6="inet6 2a03:XXXX:XXXX:XXYY::1 prefixlen 64"
ifconfig_re0_ipv6="inet6 2a03:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX::fffe prefixlen 64"
ipv6_defaultrouter="2a03:XXXX:XXXX:XXYY::fffe"
ipv6_gateway_enable="YES"
```

Here is `sysctl` flags:

```
net.inet6.ip6.forwarding: 1
net.inet6.ip6.redirect: 1
net.inet6.ip6.hlim: 64
net.inet6.ip6.maxfragpackets: 16384
net.inet6.ip6.accept_rtadv: 0
net.inet6.ip6.keepfaith: 0
net.inet6.ip6.log_interval: 5
net.inet6.ip6.hdrnestlimit: 15
net.inet6.ip6.dad_count: 1
net.inet6.ip6.auto_flowlabel: 1
net.inet6.ip6.defmcasthlim: 1
net.inet6.ip6.gifhlim: 30
net.inet6.ip6.kame_version: FreeBSD
net.inet6.ip6.use_deprecated: 1
net.inet6.ip6.rr_prune: 5
net.inet6.ip6.v6only: 1
net.inet6.ip6.rtmaxcache: 128
net.inet6.ip6.use_tempaddr: 0
net.inet6.ip6.temppltime: 86400
net.inet6.ip6.tempvltime: 604800
net.inet6.ip6.auto_linklocal: 1
net.inet6.ip6.prefer_tempaddr: 0
net.inet6.ip6.use_defaultzone: 0
net.inet6.ip6.maxfrags: 16384
net.inet6.ip6.mcast_pmtu: 0
net.inet6.ip6.no_radr: 0
net.inet6.ip6.norbit_raif: 0
net.inet6.ip6.rfc6204w3: 0
net.inet6.ip6.mcast.maxgrpsrc: 512
net.inet6.ip6.mcast.maxsocksrc: 128
net.inet6.ip6.mcast.loop: 1
net.inet6.ip6.deembed_scopeid: 1
security.jail.param.ip6.: 0
security.jail.param.ip6.saddrsel: 0
```

Please tell me, what have I missed?

Comment: This is FreeBSD? How did you get an interface named "eth2"? You seem to have "em0" and "re0" but no "eth2".

Comment: You're right, sorry. I just copied it from my notes. And they was written for Linux.

Comment: Have a look at [handbook ch30.11](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/network-ipv6.html) I think `rtsold` and `rtadvd` are needed for ipv6 routing.